# SQLSelect - Bit (true/false) as condition

Tags: databases, sql

I have a table in a MySQL-DB which is of datatype "bit". The name of this column is "abk".

If I write the following statement:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]

SQLSelect[
  conn, 
  {"dbtable_tooltips"}, 
  {"begriff_en", "abk"}, 
  SQLMemberQ[deffindcrit, SQLColumn["geltungsbereich"]]
]
```

Mathematica just returns the statement unchanged.

On the other hand if I send a statement with a wrong column-name (one that does not exist), it tells me that it doesn't exist.

So I think, that it realises that this column is there, and the name is correct, but something else is wrong.

Comment: I have just opened the connection by using an "OpenSQLConnection"-Statement. The connection itself works very well, so I can read the tables, the columns in the tables and the data. There is just an issue with this bool-column (which is a tinyint in MySQL).